# How to get a value from Session in C# and how session value will be displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ef-code-first, session-variables

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC project using entity framework code first approach.

I want to know that when a user a logs in how can we get the value from a session and how the session value be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add value to session

```
Session["UserName"] = model.UserName;
```

Retrieve value from session

```
string UserName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```